# bson.json_util datetime encode and decode best practice

Tags: python, datetime, pymongo, bson

I'm trying to encode & decode python datetime object using pymongo's bson utils.
What's best practice here?

```
>>> from bson import json_util
>>> import datetime
>>> utcnow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> x = json_util.dumps({'now': utcnow})
>>> json_util.loads(x)['now'] == utcnow
False

>>> json_util.loads(x)['now'] - utcnow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

>>> json_util.loads(x)['now'].replace(tzinfo=None) - utcnow
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86399, 999088)

>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1424297808578 / 1000) == json_util.loads(x)['now'].replace(tzinfo=None)
True
```

^ Is this really the best way?
Or write your own encode/decode and use the json lib?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `bson` rounds to milliseconds:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import bson # $ pip install bson
>>> d = datetime.utcnow(); d, abs(d - bson.loads(bson.dumps({'utcnow': d}))['utcnow'].replace(tzinfo=None))

(datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 23, 54, 47, 733092), datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 92))
```

It is a [documented behavior](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html):

> UTC datetime - The int64 is UTC milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

If you need microseconds: you could store an integer number of microseconds since the Unix epoch instead:

```
from datetime import datetime

td = utc_dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1) 
micros = td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6
```

To convert microseconds since the Unix epoch back into a naive datetime object that represents UTC time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=micros)
```

int64 (["\x12"](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)) is more than enough to represent the Unix time with the microsecond resolution (it exceeds `datetime` range anyway).

Note: POSIX timestamp "forgets" leap seconds e.g.:

```
import time

tt = time.strptime("2015-07-01 01:59:60", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ts_leap = time.mktime(tt)
tt = time.strptime("2015-07-01 02:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ts_after = time.mktime(tt)
assert ts_leap == ts_after # assuming "right" timezone is not used
```

If you care about microseconds; you should find out what your system does around leap seconds.

Time ([hardware clocks, software timers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#hardware-clocks)) on an ordinary computer are not very accurate therefore the millisecond resolution should be enough in many cases e.g., if you use `ntp` to synchronize time between machine then [NTP v3 is accurate to 1-2ms in a LAN and 10s of ms in WAN nets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97853/whats-the-best-way-to-synchronize-times-to-millisecond-accuracy-and-precision-b#comment1390694_97939).

Though, sometimes, you want to preserve digits in the input even if they are not accurate.

Comment: I don't necessarily "need" anything, I'd like to be able to encode; decode; compare == True;

Comment: @estobbart: you could compare with the millisecond resolution `abs(a-b) <= timedelta(microseconds=500)` or store microseconds as shown in the answer. It is up to you. Both are valid choices in different applications.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote but would appreciate an explanation